# npm not installing all dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, node-modules

I am using a sample nestjs project. I run "npm i" and it does run and exits with no errors or warnings. When I try to run the application, it exits with an exception `"Error: Cannot find module '@opentelemetry/sdk-node"`. I run `npm i @opentelemetry/sdk-node`. It installs it no issues. When I run the application again, it exits with an exception with another "cannot find module '..'" again. I did  this for at least 10 times and it always throws same exception with a different dependent module it cannot find. Anybody knows what could be the issue? I tried re-installing npm, node and nestjs but I get the same issue every single time.

I deleted node_modules directory, cleared the npm cache and did `npm ci`. Same issue.

Comment: Clean your system, delete node_modules and package-lock.json. Then NPM install. Hopefully sorted.

Comment: I did all of that and I did clean the cache, same issue. Thanks.

Comment: that package is not included when you generate a new Nest project via CLI and needs to be added manually (the way you have described it `npm i <SOME_DEPENDENCY>`). please check if needed dependencies are defined in your package.json file and that you are calling the `npm i` command at the root of that project.